# How can you print a staircase out of stars from right to left and not the other way around like it does normally?

Tags: java, netbeans

So I just have no idea how could i print a staircase from right to left...

Right now the code works but it prints from left.. (this code is in a method)
Here is the code:

```
int row = 1;
while (row <= size) {
       printStars(row);
       row = row + 1;
```

also i was supposed to create a method that would print a number of spaces:

```
    int space= 0;
 
    while (space < amount) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        space = space + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Start at the high number and subtract it for each loop cycle `row = row - 1;`, then work out how many spacers you need and print it out followed by the stair character`printStars(spacer+row);.`

Comment: I forgot that I also was supposed to create a method that would print a number of spaces here it is:          int space = 0;
     
        while (space < amount) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            space = space + 1;
        }

Comment: I've answered this, please take the time to read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/8616470) on homework questions. It will help you ask them more usefully, which will help you get useful answers back in return. :)

Answer (score 0):

To print your stars in the opposite order, you can simply reverse the logic of your loop such that it begins at `size` and approaches zero:

```java
int row = size;
while (row > 0) {
  printStars(row);
  row = row - 1;
}
```